# ElasticSearch - Restrict primary and replica shards count on nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ElasticSearch 7.16.2 cluster running with three nodes (2 master , 1 Voting node). An index has two primary shards and two replicas, and on restarting a node, both primary shards move to single node. How to restrict index in a nodes to have one primary shard and one replica each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [index level shard allocation settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html#shard-allocation-filtering) to achieve that, **it might be not that straight forward and it's a bit complex setting and can cause further unbalance when you have a changing nodes and indices in the cluster**.

In order to avoid the issue which happens on the **node restart**, you must disable the shard allocation and shard rebalance before starting your nodes in Elasticsearch cluster.

**Command to disable allocation**

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
 "persistent":{
    "cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "all"
    }
}
```

**Command to disable rebalance**

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
 "persistent":{
    "cluster.routing.rebalance.enable": "all"
    }
}
```

**Apart from that, you can use the [reroute API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html) to manually move the shards to a node in Elasticsearch to fix your current shard allocation.**

Comment: Thanks, this resolves my issue, just the request to disable allocation and rebalance for 7.16.2 should be , 
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "all",
    "cluster.routing.rebalance.enable": "all"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

the config is `index.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node`. but you have a problem. first of all I assume you have three `data node`. (if you don't have, increase the data nodes.).

the problem is you have 4 primary and replica shard in total and one node must assign two shards to itself. so you could not the set index.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node to 1. at least it must be 2 and your problem not solved.

the config is dynamic: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/increase-shard-limit.html

also you could set `cluster.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node` config for cluster.

Comment: this will not address the root cause, OP should disable the shard allocation and rebalance during nodes restart to avoid the issue in first place, please refer my answer for full detail.

Comment: Although thanks for providing the relevant configs to control the shards settings, it would be useful for sure..